# Access Vue Instance Using this

Tags: javascript, vue.js

When I try to use this in my VueJs methods I get the following error

> this is undefined

I think that I shouldn't use arrow functions because their `this` does not bind to the context I expect it to.

I try with a regular function and get the error above.

### What I've tried so far

```js
methods: {
  connection(){
    new elasticsearch.Client({...});
    
    client.search({...})
          .then(function (resp) {
            var hits = resp.aggregations;
            this.tmp = hits[1].value;
          }, function (err) {
            console.trace(err.message);
          });                   
   }
}
```

I cannot use the `this` that I want to in the  functions passed to `.search` and `.then` . How can I have `this` bind to my VueJs instance so I can access `data`, `computed`, etc...?

Comment: I'm not sure about what are you trying to do here, is `tmp` a data property? Because I think you are trying to assign a value to `tmp` property but `tmp` looks like a global var and don't belongs to `this`. You should try to use `let` and not `var` also, because they are local variables.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use [arrow function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions) to save `this` context, and don't forget that inside Vue methods `this` refers to the current instance.

```js
data() {
  return {
    counter:0,
    connections:2,
    tmp: 0,
  }
},
methods: {
  connection() {
    // ...
    var client = new elasticsearch.Client({
      host: 'xxxxxxxxxxxx'
    });
    client.search({
      [...]
    }).then((resp) => {
      var hits = resp.aggregations;
      this.tmp = hits[1].value;
    }, (err) => {
      console.trace(err.message);
    });
  }
}
```

Comment: @Quentin_otd You're welcome. Also, don't forget that `client.search()` call is asynchronous, so if you want to `console.log(tmp)` then you should do that in `.then()` handler.

Answer (score 0):

You can assign `this` variable to local variable(**self**) and use it in .then function

```
   data () {
    return {
        counter:0,
        connections:2
    }
},
methods: {
    connection(){
        var self = this;
        var tmp=0
        var elasticsearch = require('elasticsearch');
        var client = new elasticsearch.Client({
        host: 'xxxxxxxxxxxx'
        });
        client.search({
        "index":"400000",
        [...]
        }
        }).then(function (resp) {
            var hits = resp.aggregations;
            self.tmp=hits[1].value;
        }, function (err) {
            console.trace(err.message);
        });   
        console.log("tmp:",tmp)

    }
}
```

Comment: Refrain from using `self`, it's a synonym for `window`, although not a reference, a copy.  Still, use another word not used by the JavaScript engine.  Just in case an imported library is using it.

Comment: I would typically use `_this` or `vm`

Comment: Did not work unfortunatly, console.log(tmp) would always print out "0"

Comment: @Quentin_otd , please add this console.log('tmp:',self.tmp) line in .then function, it will work.