# ajax call back function can not access the variable in vuejs

Tags: jquery, ajax, vue.js

i have some problem with ajax call back function. I use ajax and vuejs together, after a make an ajax request in vue method, i would like to access the variable of vuejs but it not working. Here is my code

This is my vuejs function: in this function i tried to upload image to server with ajax

```js
submitFile() {
   let url = base_url+"/acp/attach/upload";
   let formData = new FormData();
   let mod_name = $("#vinpModName").val();
   let mod_id = $("#vinpModId").val();
   let file_title = $("#file_title").val();

   //handle multi files upload
   for( var i = 0; i < this.files.length; i++ ){
    let file = this.files[i];
    var imgData = '';

    if ( i > 0 ) file_title = file_title + ' ' + i;

    formData.append('images', file);
    formData.append('mod_name', mod_name);
    formData.append('mod_id', mod_id);
    formData.append('title', file_title);

    $.ajax({
     url: url,
     data: formData,
     contentType: false,
     processData: false,
     enctype: 'multipart/form-data',
     type: "POST",
     success: function (data) {
      var response = jQuery.parseJSON(data); console.log(this.myUploadData);
      imgData = response.imgData;

      if ( response.code == 1 ) {
       SwalAlert.fire({
        icon: 'error',
        title: response.text,
       })
      } else {
       SwalAlert.fire({
        icon: 'success',
        title: response.text,
       })
      }

     },
     error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrow) { //console.log(errorThrow);
      SwalAlert.fire({
       icon: 'error',
       title: 'Có lỗi xảy ra khi upload! Vui lòng thử lại sau',
      })
     }
    })
    console.log(this.myUploadData);
    //this.myUploadData.push(imgData);

   }


  },
```

in the function i log the vuejs variable 2 time, 1 worked and 1 does not work

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/52rvC.png)

here, the result when i tested in browser

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HZPcv.png)

Can anyone tell me what's wrong with my script?
i want to access to the this.myUploadData and push the return object to this variable
Can any one help me with this!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Access Vue Instance Using this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55567884/access-vue-instance-using-this)

Comment: this won't work for me :(

Comment: Can you explain what's not working? You've changed `success: function (data) {` to `success: data => {` and moved `this.myUploadData.push(imgData);` into the success callback and it's still not working?

Comment: yes, that's right, the error log tell me that this.myUploadData is not defined

Comment: Have you defined `myUploadData` in the [Vue instance data](https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/instance.html#Data-and-Methods)? Could you update your question to show?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've included a snippet of a Vue app with the same format as yours, it uses a different api and adds the response to an array, which then displays on the page. Hopefully you'll find it useful in your understanding.

It uses arrow functions in the success callback, so that you can use `this`.

Defines `myUploadData` in the Vue instance data, so that it's reactive.

Only pushes to myUploadData once the request has finished, in the `success` callback (Thanks @Renaud).

```js
new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data: () => {
    return {
      myUploadData: []
    }
  },
  methods: {
    submitFile() {
      $.ajax({
        url: `https://us-central1-dadsofunny.cloudfunctions.net/DadJokes/random/jokes/1`,
        headers: {
          Accept: "application/json"
        },
        success: data => {
          //Request has finished
          this.myUploadData.push(data);
        },
        error: data => {
          alert(data);
        }
      });

      //Request hasn't finished yet
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <div>
    <button type="button" @click="submitFile">Submit File</button>

  </div>

  <div v-for="uploadData in myUploadData">
    {{uploadData}}
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to do that within the success callback also.
When your second console.log is evaluated the async request has not finished at all.

Comment: i tried to log in the success callback already but it not work too